# Finding a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have some problem with a question related to linear maps. I know the solution but I can not understand the reason behind it.

---

For any polynomial $p∈P^2$ let:
$$q_p(t):=p(−1)+p(0)t+p(1)t^2+p(2)t^3$$

Consider the map $φ:P^2→P^3$ defined by $φ(p):=q_p$.

Prove that the map $φ$ is linear and find its matrix in the pair of bases $\{1,t,t^2\}$ and $\{1,t,t^2,t^3 \}$.

---

My solution is take each vector from the basis of $P^2$ and apply map to it. For example the first element in the basis is $1$. Applying $φ$ to it, I will get [1, 1, 1, 1]. So the result will be:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
-1 &0  & 1 & 2\\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}

It sounds reasonable to me: if I take any vector in $P^2$ (1x3) and multiply it with (3x4) matrix (apply the map on the vector) I will get 1x4 vector in $P^3$.

The problem is that the solution is 4x3 matrix which is actually a transpose of matrix I derived. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of convention.  When we say "give a matrix wrt to a pair of bases" we mean, a matrix $M$ so that $w = Mv$ whenever $v$ and $w$ are column vectors of some vector $x$ and the corresponding vector $\phi(x)$ in the bases given.  There's nothing actually wrong with your reasoning, you are just using row vectors instead of the column vectors.

Comment: And in particular, when using row vectors, applying a linear transformation corresponds to multiplication of the corresponding matrix on the *right*, rather than the left as is conventional.